# GetOwinContext is not working in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, owin

It always says **HttpContext** not include the define of GetOwinContext(),I try to download the .net core owin but I don't know how to implement the same function.
The code belows can be complied in asp.net 5 .

```
private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
{
    get
    {                
        return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no `GetOwinContext()` for Asp.Net core. Use `HttpContext.Authentication` instead.

Comment: `HttpContext.Authentication` is obsolete in ASP.Net Core 2.1.

Comment: Yes, its right that HttpContext.Authentication is obsolete in ASP.NET Core 2.1+ and it will be removed in future. Microsoft recommends the use of AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions instead.

Comment: My head is spinning.  DotNet is all over the freaking map these days.